# Solving an equation involving $\log_{10}$

Tags: logarithms

If
$$\log_{10}(x)\log_{10}(2) = 2$$
What is $x$ ?

WolframAlpha says $x = e^{\frac2{\log_{10}(2)}}$

But i don't understand why it is.. Please explain it. Thanks

Comment: It would help to know *exactly* what you wrote as your input to WA, because the answer you say WA gave is *not* the answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

There's really not much to it, but you probably used $\ln$ when asking W|A (`log` is interpreted as the natural logaritm by default).
$$\log_{10} x \log_{10} 2 = 2 \\
 \Rightarrow \log_{10} x = \frac2{\log_{10}2} \\
\Rightarrow x = 10^{\log_{10} x} = 10^{\frac2{\log_{10}2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

That's because, when you write down $\log$ in WolframAlpha, it is interpreted as $\log_e$ or $\ln$. So WolframAlpha solved the equation

$$\ln(x)\ln(2)=2$$

Which is solved by first dividing the equation by $\ln 2$, obtaining
$$ln(x) = \frac{2}{\ln 2}$$

Then using the fact that $a=b\iff e^a=e^b$ to get

$$(x=)e^{\ln x} = e^{\frac{2}{\ln2}}$$

Comment: Except, oddly, WA seems to get the $\log_{10}(2)$ right - it doesn't interpret it as $\ln 2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews No, WA writes log, which is the natural log. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+log%28x%29log%282%29%3D2 for proof.

Comment: This is what the OP wrote was WA's answer:  $$x = e^{\frac2{\log_{10}(2)}}$$ That's the correct answer to $\log(x)\log_{10}(2)=2$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews True, but since (if you only followed the link I provided) WA returns $\frac{2}{\log (2)}$ without explicitly saying that it is $\log_2$, and since it is obvious that the OP did not know that WA interprets $\log$ as $\log_e$ and not $\log_{10}$, it is safe to assume that the OP, when reading WA's result, interpreted $\log$ as $\log_{10}$.

Comment: So, in other words, you are not explaining to the OP why he got the answer he got from WA, nor do you mention that your answer is different, nor do you answer the original question.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Actually, I explain to the OP that he misunderstood the answer he got from WA, therefore already answering his original question (why is WA's answer such and such) in my first sentence. I then also explain how WA interpreted his input, and how to solve the equation that WA understood. From the solution, it is very evident how to solve the equation he needs to solve. I did not write how to solve that one, because I think he can put in 5 minutes of work and do it himself.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a rearrangement of variables.

So, say:

- a = log(x)
- b = log(2)
- c = 2

Then we have a*b = c, which means a=c/b

To get x by itself simply take the exponential of both sides (because the exponential of the log of x is just x).